# how to open modify a java project format (. jar)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I want to open a java project (.jar) to edit it with eclipse but I do not know how.

Comment: A Jar is not a Java project.  It's (usually) a collection of compiled Java classes.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a zip file.

You can rename the file from .jar to .zip.
Then edit with the usual zip tools on your platform (not in Eclipse directly).

The files it contains are not the Java project files, but .class files and a manifest (XML table of contents), etc. You usually don't edit the archive directly, since the manifest would no longer match. But you can open it this way to see what it contains.

Comment: okkey thank you very much for youre answer ^^